# How to collect or reparse JSON Using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, collect

I would like to be able with Python to collect or reparse JSON using the first level key.

There is a JSON like this:

```
[{
    "system": "test111",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.000000", "value": 0 }
},
{
    "system": "test111",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.111111", "value": 11 }
},
{
    "system": "test111",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.222222", "value": 22 }
},
{
    "system": "test222",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.333333", "value": 33 }
},
{
    "system": "test222",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.444444", "value": 44 }
},
{
    "system": "test333",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.555555", "value": 55 }
},
{
    "system": "test333",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.666666", "value": 66 }
},
{
    "system": "test444",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.777777", "value": 77 }
},
{
    "system": "test444",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.888888", "value": 88 }
},
{
    "system": "test555",
    "data": { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.999999", "value": 99 }
}]
```

And I want to regenerate JSON like this:

```
[{
    "system": "test111",
    "data": [{ "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.000000", "value": 0 }, { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.111111", "value": 11 }, { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.222222", "value": 22 }]
},
{
    "system": "test222",
    "data": [{ "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.333333", "value": 33 }, { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.444444", "value": 44 }]
},
{
    "system": "test333",
    "data": [{ "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.555555", "value": 55 }, { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.666666", "value": 66 }]
},
{
    "system": "test444",
    "data": [{ "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.777777", "value": 77 }, { "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.888888", "value": 88 }]
},
{
    "system": "test555",
    "data": [{ "title": "SomeValue", "time": "2022-10-22T10:36:43.999999", "value": 99 }]
}]
```

In short, how to collect all system key values and group the results accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `groupby` and do something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = []#insert data here
result = []
for key, value in groupby(data, lambda x: x["system"]):
     item = {"system": key, "data": []}
     item["data"] += [x["data"] for x in value]
     result.append(item)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{'system': 'test111', 'data': [{'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.000000', 'value': 0}, {'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.111111', 'value': 11}, {'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.222222', 'value': 22}]}, {'system': 'test222', 'data': [{'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.333333', 'value': 33}, {'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.444444', 'value': 44}]}, {'system': 'test333', 'data': [{'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.555555', 'value': 55}, {'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.666666', 'value': 66}]}, {'system': 'test444', 'data': [{'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.777777', 'value': 77}, {'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.888888', 'value': 88}]}, {'system': 'test555', 'data': [{'title': 'SomeValue', 'time': '2022-10-22T10:36:43.999999', 'value': 99}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.loads()` to convert your JSON into a dictionary

Then a simple loop over the `system` key should allow you to regroup the `data` field into a list of dictionaries.

You can convert the new dictionary you created back into a JSON file using `json.dumps()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).